# Vertical Radio-Buttons with table/ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to achieve radio-buttons in multiple HTML-Table-Columns.
The number of Columns and Rows is dynamic (data-driven).

Example:

| Input 1 | Input 2 | Input n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| O (group 1) | O (group 2) | O (group n) |
| O (group 1) | O (group 2) | O (group n) |
| O (group 1) | O (group 2) | O (group n) |

My code creates the table like this:

```
<table>
  <ui:repeat value="rows" var="row">
    <tr>
      <ui:repeat value="cols" var="col">
        <td>
          O (group col.id)
        </td>
      </ui:repeat>
    </tr>
  </ui:repeat>
</table>
```

Now the question is: How can i create the needed radio-buttons the JSF-way?

All available components don't work this way:

- p:selectOneRadio with custom layout doesn't play nice with ui:repeat, because i need one per column (not one per column and row)
- h:selectBooleanCheckbox won't render as radio-buttons, so no MUTEX per group and wrong HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without `ui:repeat` by applying some CSS. For example:

```html
<div style="display: flex">
    <p:selectOneRadio id="group1" layout="responsive" columns="1">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Group1 Option1" itemValue="Option1"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Group1 Option2" itemValue="Option2"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Group1 Option3" itemValue="Option3"/>
    </p:selectOneRadio>

    <p:selectOneRadio id="group2" layout="responsive" columns="1">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Group2 Option1" itemValue="Option1"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Group2 Option2" itemValue="Option2"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Group2 Option3" itemValue="Option3"/>
    </p:selectOneRadio>

    <p:selectOneRadio id="group3" layout="responsive" columns="1">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Group3 Option1" itemValue="Option1"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Group3 Option2" itemValue="Option2"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Group3 Option3" itemValue="Option3"/>
    </p:selectOneRadio>
</div>
```

Comment: For more complex use-cases one could use css grid with named `grid-area`s and `grid-template-areas`.